# Removing "product.php" in URL using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url

The current URL: `http://www.example.com/product.php/sample-product.html`.

I want change it to: `http://www.example.com/sample-product.html`

Comment: I remember adding "But first please find the duplicate (which exist!)" to my comment.

Comment: Apart from that, what is your code now? What have you tried so far? Is there a reason why you think this might not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it with URL Rewriting like that :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Place this code in .htaccess at root.